# Send email with multiple dynamic attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I'm trying to send an email with a dynamic number of attachments, so I surfed the forum and I found the solution below, but it doesn't work, it returns the error

> Exception: Invalid argument: attachments

```
var attach = [];
for (ii = 0; ii < 6; ii ++) {
    if (impiegati[ii][4]) {
      attach.push(DriveApp.getFileById(impiegati[ii][4]).getId());
    };
  };  
MailApp.sendEmail(dest, obj, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: attach});
```

Comment: attach should be an array of files not file ids. Remove the getId()

Comment: ok Cooper, thx it works. but I'm sending google spreadsheets as attachments and the receiver found pdf document, not a spreadsheet. The sheets are properly shared with receivers. How to send google sheets instead of PDF?

Comment: I would recommend asking another question and provide a complete example of the code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Cooper you need to remove the `getId()`:

```js
var attach = [];
for (ii = 0; ii < 6; ii ++) {
    if (impiegati[ii][4]) {
      attach.push(DriveApp.getFileById(impiegati[ii][4]));
    };
  };  
MailApp.sendEmail(dest, obj, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: attach});
```